# Deployment of Azure virtual network gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network-gateway

I am trying to create a virtual network gateway in Azure Portal and whenever I try I get the following error.

```
vnet-gateway-d was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region
```

Now that is the name of the gateway I am creating so I don't know why its complaining about that. I have checked and it is set to east us as is the vnet.

Let me know what other information I can provide.

Comment: First verify that your resource exists by Resource Explorer or shell. Make sure no case sensitivity is a problem in naming. Then try with another vnet gateway name. Try creating with shell instead of UI (if thats what you are using )

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in my environment I got the same error like below:

```
VNet1GW was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region
```

[image]

This issue usually occurs if virtual network and the virtual network gateway aren’t in the same region and same resource group. Because the resources are in different regions, it's impossible to create the gateway.

You can make use of below command to check virtual network region in your resource group:

```
Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName "<RGName>" | Select-Object Name, Location | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

[image]

In portal if you are selecting region as `Eastus` region while creating the virtual network gateway by default when you select virtual network the drop-down displays only the `Eastus`  virtual network like below:

[image]

Now virtual network gateway is deployed successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

[Create a route-based virtual network gateway: PowerShell - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/create-routebased-vpn-gateway-powershell)